# How to Watch Deep Data Structures in Vue (Arrays and Objects)

Tags: vue.js

I have a object variable in which i need to watch some of the keys

My object

```
user{
 name,
 address,
 city,
 dob
}
```

So I need to watch address and city properties

so the way i am doing it as below

```
watch:{
   'user.address' : (new,old)=>{
             //do something    
          },
   'user.city' : (new,old)=>{
             //do something    
          },
}
```

Now what i want let say in future if i want to watch some more properties inside user object the one way is to add new watcher for that property as i did above, is there any other way that i can do it dynamically without writing watch everytime.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by using `deep` watcher option:

```
watch:{
  user: {
    handler(new,old) {...},
    deep: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Estus I tried it is watching for all the properties inside that object I just wanted to watch specific properties, can you help me how to achieve that, as I wanted to check if some property value is changing than do something or else not.

Comment: You can use imperative watcher like `this.$watch(() => pick(this.user, ['address', '...']), (newVal, oldVal) => ...)`, or define a key dynamically for $watch . This could be XY problem, maybe you need computeds or to make a state easier to handle. I can't think of a good reason to do what you asked about.

Comment: Sorry i am new to Vuejs i am working on my first project so don`t know how, but i am trying to update one properties based on changes happening in some properties. my user object has multiple properties but i wanted to watch only some of them

Comment: As said above, this is possibly solved with computeds. In my experience, the overuse of watchers means that computeds aren't used enough.

Comment: can you please update your answer with more details, sorry i am new so asking Thank you

Comment: I can't provide more details because I don't know what you're trying to do. "do something " doesn't really help here. Basically it's https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#

Comment: so pick method i need to define in computed property right? and it will return field i need to watch right?

Comment: Also i have user registration form which has multiple properties, i need to check if any user edited there address than i need to update one property based on those changes, in my case if user edit address, city, zipcode, country than value of one property should update. hope i am able to clear it.

Comment: It depends on what exactly should happen on those changes. Unless you need to compare old and new value, it's the case for a computed.